# if else not working on jstl

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

```
hiii i am using spring MVC and i have list which  ia m sending as my response to  jsp but ibn in this jsp i have a attribute isnew which is of type boolean so i want a comaprison on this attribute soo  sode is

    <core:forEach var="i" items="${loginsuccess}" >
        <core:if test="${i.isNew eq true}"> 
                <core:out value="${i.notofication}"></core:out> </br>   
                </core:if>
        </core:forEach>

DAO CODE

@Autowired
    SessionFactory usermanagementSessionFactory;

    public ModelAndView  getNotifications(int id){

        System.out.println("Method ios called");
        Session session = usermanagementSessionFactory.openSession();

        System.out.println("after Getting Session");
        int  id1  = id;
        System.out.println(id1);
        Query query=(Query) session.getNamedQuery("getNotification");
        query.setInteger("userId",id1);

        List<Message> list1= query.list();

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("notifications");

         mv.addObject("loginsuccess" ,list1);
        return mv;



}

 its not working please suggest me how can i resolve this problem
```

to check how it works.
    i want to show the notification only when it is new , this is the dao code which returns the login success and controller only calling this code as a simple method

Comment: Answer to what? What's the question? And what 'else'? There is no 'else' in your page, or in JSTL either. 'Not working' isn't an adequate problem description. Clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
<core:if test="${i.new}">
```

Comment: hiii @Alex i want to use else part also with this so what i need to doo

Comment: @Nav Kumar Use `<c:choose><c:when></c:when><otherwise></otherwise></c:choose>`

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
<c:choose>

   <c:when test="${i.new}"> 
//to do statement
   </c:when>
//to do statement
   <otherwise>

   </otherwise>
</c:choose>
```